# Mount windows share fails using command line but works using Files/Connect to Server

Tags: server, mount, 20.04, fstab, cifs

On my new PC running Ubuntu 20.04, I cannot connect and mount our organisation's windows share //server/share either by setting up fstab or by manual mounting such as:
`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=xxxx,vers=1.0 //server/share /media/share` (dmesg: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2) or:
`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=xxxx,vers=2.0 //server/share /media/share` (CIFS VFS:  BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \server\share  CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2).

I have tried a lot more variations than the two. It has worked for years on my old PC. The funny thing is that Ubuntu's own Files application connects easily ("Other Locations" > "Connect to server") with typing into the Server Address box  `smb://server/share` and then user name and password. (using smb://server/share in `mount` does not work).

I have tried many ideas around on the net, but all in vain. So any feedback would be awesome!